# React test if something hasn't happened after useEffect

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm using `react-testing-library` and `jest` to test if my API is not invoked when a certain prop is set. Currently the test succeeds immediately without finishing the useEffect() call. How do I make the test wait until `useEffect` has finished, so I can be certain the API has not been called?

The code:

```js
const MyComponent = ({ dontCallApi }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const asyncFunction = async () => {
      if (dontCallApi) {
        return
      }

      await callApi()
    }
    asyncFunction
  }, [])

  return <h1>Hi!</h1>
}

it('should not call api when dontCallApi is set', async () => {
  const apiSpy = jest.spyOn(api, 'callApi')
  render(<MyComponent dontCallApi />)
  expect(apiSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you could spy on `React.useEffect` and provide an alternative implementation. `jest.spyOn(React, "useEffect").mockImplementation((f) => f())`
so now you dont't have to care about the handling of useEffect anymore.

If you also want to test useEffect in a descent way you may extract the logic in a custom hook and use the [testing library for hooks](https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library) with the `renderHooks` function to test your use case.

I would test your Component like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { MyComponent } from "./Example";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { mocked } from "ts-jest/utils";
jest.mock("./api", () => ({
  callApi: jest.fn(),
}));
import api from "./api";
const mockApi = mocked(api);

jest.spyOn(React, "useEffect").mockImplementation((f) => f());
describe("MyComponet", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  it("should not call api when dontCallApi is set", async () => {
    render(<MyComponent dontCallApi />);
    expect(mockApi.callApi).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
  });

  it("should call api when is not set", async () => {
    render(<MyComponent />);
    expect(mockApi.callApi).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

**Edit 03.07.2020**

I recently found out that there is a possibility to query something like you wanted without mocking `useEffect`. You could simply use the async utilities of react testing library and get the following:

```
import React from "react";

import { MyComponent } from "./TestComponent";
import { render, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import { api } from "./api";

const callApiSpy = jest.spyOn(api, "callApi");

beforeEach(() => {
  callApiSpy.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve());
});
afterEach(() => {
  callApiSpy.mockClear();
});
describe("MyComponet", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  it("should not call api when dontCallApi is set", async () => {
    render(<MyComponent dontCallApi />);
    await waitFor(() => expect(callApiSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0));
  });

  it("should call api when is not set", async () => {
    render(<MyComponent />);
    await waitFor(() => expect(callApiSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
  });
});
```

to get more information about this take a look at [the async utilities docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I guess creating a custom hook and testing that would be the only way to test the logic inside the useEffect call. This seems to be really hard to test in an integration test without mocking stuff... Although I guess in an integration test you're not testing at this level.